# Change built react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

I have deleted a react project but have it’s built version on a server. Is there a way to reverse the build process? I’ve read that doing changes to an already build project is nearly impossible. Any help? (It’s is gatsby-react Template I’ve used but with major changes to design etc.)

Comment: If the code is minified, you'll have trouble about the named functions. If it's bundled, you'll have trouble with module aggregations. Maybe this can help you at least a bit: https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/64/what-is-a-good-tools-to-reverse-the-effects-of-minify-on-javascript

Comment: The main changes I have to do concern images and CSS not even JavaScript or anything functional. Additionally I only have to change 1 link.